# How can i add different data to 3 fragment in 3 tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to know that how can i add some different data like an array to each fragments that are in TabLayout?
i mean that fragment1 show array1, fragment2 show array2 and fragment3 show array3

the below is my code for Tablayout:

```
public class PoshtibaniActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_poshtibani);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_empty);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("پشتیبانی");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(2);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "پیامهای دریافتی");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "پیامهای ارسالی");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "ارسال پیام");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it was solved but now i want to add data to theme. i dont know how to do it. because i want make the fragmens one and use them in different activities @AdityaVyas

Comment: what do you mean data to theme??what you trying to achieve?

Comment: when user comes to my activity i want to show data with that fragment. i dont know how to use that fragments. where should i write that code to bring data from data base. because i want to use fragments in different activities @AdityaVyas

Comment: in which manner you need to display? listview or gridview?

Comment: i have Recycler view in each fragment. @AdityaVyas

Comment: then what is the issue you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use SetArguement for each of your fragments.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "پیامهای دریافتی",MY_ARRAY_1,MY_SEC_ARRAY_1);
   adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "پیامهای ارسالی",MY_ARRAY_2,MY_SEC_ARRAY_2);
   adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "ارسال پیام",MY_ARRAY_3,MY_SEC_ARRAY_3);
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

then in your adapter :

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title,Object data,ArrayList<MY_DATA_MODEL> array2) {
    Bundle mBundle=new Bundle();
    mBundle.put("dataArray",data);
    mBundle.put("dataArray2",array2);
    fragment.setArgument(mBundle);
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
```

Now in each of your fragments, you should override setArguments and get your data from bundle there.

Don't forget to make your data model parcelable if you want to pass them in bundle and intents.

Comment: thanks. data is json object? if i have more than 1 array what should i do? @smartiz

Comment: You can pass whatever you like, but pay attention if you use a complex data model, you should make your model Parcelable. then you can pass it with intents.
I edited my answer for two Array. @moji

Comment: thanks to you. so how can i use these fragments for more than 1 activity? i mean that i use these fragment in activityA and if user went to ActivityB then i use these fragments in ActivityB. i want to make 3 fragment for 5 activity that are similar together. @smartiz

Comment: i didn't understand your meaning. but if you mean you create those fragment once and use it everywhere, avoid doing that.
you cant pass fragments in BUNDLES. you should make a static reference to the adapter or array of fragments which cause lots of MEMORY LEAK !
Just make a new adapter and pass your variabels. @moji

Comment: yes i want to make those fragment one and use them everywhere. i have 15 activity that have the same layout but their data is different. if want to make 3 fragment for all of them i should make 45 fragment in my app. is it correct in programming? can i send array of data to that fragments? @smartiz

Comment: Dear @moji , all you need is just 3 fragments and one adapter !!! that fulfill all your needs.
in each activity, just pass new array of data to your adapter ! I mean the setupViewPager function in your activity

Comment: Can you come to chat with me. because here is comment we dont have permission to make a lot of comments. i want to help me more if you can. please @smartiz

Comment: I'm at your service dear @moji . How can we chat ?

Comment: thanks a lot dear. i have registered for 2 days in the stackoverflow and i dont have permission to chat here. can you chat by mobile? in whatsapp or telegram or viber. this is my number: +98-935-596-3590   @smartiz

Answer (score 0):

view pager file

```
  public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


  String[] title = {
    "stringA",
    "stringB",
    "stringC",
  }


    public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  /** Show a Fragment based on the position of the current screen */
        if (position == 0) {
            return FragmentA.newInstance(title);
        } 
         else if(position==1)
          {
            return new FragmentB.newInstance(title);
          }

         else  { return FragmentC.newInstance(title);}
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Fragment file

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


public static FragmentA newInstance(String [] s) {
    FragmentA A = new FragmentA();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("elist",s);
    A.setArgumentas(args);
    return A;
}

}


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
     ViewGroup containerObject,
     Bundle savedInstanceState){
     //here is your arguments
     Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

    //here is your list array 
    String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("elist");   
 }



public class FragmentB extends Fragment {


public static FragmentB newInstance(String [] s) {
    FragmentB B = new FragmentB();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("elist",s);
    B.setArgumentas(args);
    return B;
}

}


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
     ViewGroup containerObject,
     Bundle savedInstanceState){
     //here is your arguments
     Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

    //here is your list array 
    String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("elist");   
 }


public class FragmentC extends Fragment {


public static FragmentC newInstance(String [] s) {
    FragmentC C = new FragmentC();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("elist",s);
    C.setArgumentas(args);
    return C;
}

}


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
     ViewGroup containerObject,
     Bundle savedInstanceState){
     //here is your arguments
     Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

    //here is your list array 
    String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("elist");   
 }
```

Comment: thanks. you mean that i should make java file for each fragment? @mrugesh-thaker